# use list tuple as 2d index to loop through another 2d list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I built a list like this:

num_rows and num cols are from list aaa

```
for i in range(num_rows):
     for j in range(num_cols):
         if (aaa[i][j] == 0):
               bbb.append((i,j))
     pass
pass
```

now I have another 2d list called ccc with floats in. I want to use the tuple from bbb as index for ccc (the specific row and col). I need to do a np.sum after on particular indices. So I have tried something like this:

```
np.sum(ccc[k][l] for (k,l) in bbb)
```

I am new to python and I know it is not right. I barely learned how to write for loops... But is there a way to do something like this?

Thank you all.

Comment: I am not sure what this means, but seems like it would ignore the condition I need: the integer in aaa need to be 0? Can you explain a bit please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both `aaa`, `ccc` are numpy array, use `np.sum(ccc[aaa == 0])`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> aaa = np.array([
...     [1, 0, 1],
...     [0, 1, 0],
...     [1, 0, 1],
... ])
>>> ccc = np.array([
...     [1, 2, 3],
...     [4, 5, 6],
...     [7, 8, 9],
... ])

>>> aaa == 0
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> ccc[aaa == 0]
array([2, 4, 6, 8])

>>> np.sum(ccc[aaa == 0])
20
```

Comment: Shouldn't `!=` be `==`?

Comment: @user2357112, You're right. I found it just after posted the answer. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this method but I got an index error: index 20 is out of bound for axis 0 with size 20. This happens because my aaa and ccc have different sizes. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user3332241, Try `np.sum(ccc[(aaa == 0)[:len(ccc)]])`

Comment: @falsetru Now it is saying for axis 1, what is happenning?

Comment: @user3332241, I don't understand what you mean. Could you update your question with the actual value of the `aaa`, `ccc` ?

Comment: @falsetru I found where the error is, it's solved now :D thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular `sum`. `np.sum` expects an array-like object:

```
sum(ccc[k][l] for (k,l) in bbb)
```

Note that if you're using NumPy, you probably shouldn't be using all these lists and non-NumPy operations. Here's what your code would look like with `aaa` and `ccc` as NumPy arrays:

```
ccc[aaa==0].sum()
```

Much less code, and runs much faster than the list-based solution.

Additional note: you don't need to end loops with `pass`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this method but I got an index error: index 20 is out of bound for axis 0 with size 20. This happens because my aaa and ccc have different sizes. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user3332241: If aaa and ccc are supposed to have different sizes, your program likely has a fundamental design flaw. If they're not supposed to have different sizes, you may have a bug in the code that creates them. I can't tell what the fix should be.

Comment: You are right, it is a bug. It's solved now :D thank you